# Measure takes the value of infinity

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If a measure $P$ can take value of $+\infty $, does countable additivity ($\sigma$-additivity) imply continuity at $\emptyset$? If not, what is a good example?

Comment: Not set-theory. Plus, $P$ is not a probability, so the tag should be measure-theory instead.)

Comment: The reals with Lebesgue measure form a counterexample, right? Take $A_n=(n,\infty)$. Their intersection is empty.